# Execute command for multiple files

Tags: normal-mode, repeated-commands

I often want to run multiple `vim` commands on multiple files.

Consider the files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`: I might want to run `:retab` and then some `:%s/ /, /` for instance.

How can I "pipe" this through Vim?

Answer (score 6):

First, you are running Vim, not Vi, because the latter does not offer the `retab` command.

Assuming the file should be modified (that is what `x` does below), you can pipe the commands to Ex improved mode this way:

```
printf '%s\n' 'retab' '%s/ /, /' 'x' | vim -E file1.txt
```

Now, bear in mind that Ex will skip your `.vimrc`, so `retab` will not take
`tabstop` and `expandtab` values from that file. Of course, you can just manually supply them, for example,

```
printf '%s\n' 'set expandtab' 'retab' '%s/ /, /' 'x' | vim -E file1.txt
```

To operate on various files (matching `file[digit].txt`), just wrap it in a shell loop,

```
for file in file[0-9].txt; do
    printf '%s\n' 'set expandtab' 'retab' '%s/ /, /' 'x' | vim -E "$file"
done
```

Comment: Could one also create a macro instead and use this with `vim` for each file?

Comment: @stephanmg I think so, except maybe for the `x`. Do you want that case covered too? If so, please edit the question.

Comment: No, this will be fine @Quasimodo.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`-c`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) argument in the command-line to run commands in Vim after opening a file. You can pass it multiple times to run the several separate commands. Once you run the editing commands, you'll probably want to include a [`:wq`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Awq) to have Vim save your changes and quit.

```
$ vim -c 'retab' -c '%s/ /, /' -c 'wq' file1.txt
```

You can of course use that inside a `for` loop to run it on each of your text files.

Another option is to open all the files in Vim and then use [`:argdo`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdo) to run a sequence of commands in all the files in the argument list. In that case, you should join all your commands using [`|`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) (which is the command separator in Vim) and you should end each `:argdo` with an [`:update`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aupdate) so that it will save the file (if necessary) before proceeding to the next one. This is important, otherwise Vim might refuse to move away from the current buffer, which would break your `:argdo` execution.

```
$ vim file*.txt
```

Then inside Vim:

```
:argdo retab | %s/ /, / | update
```

All your files will have been updated and you'll be in the last file in your argument list. At this point you can simply quit Vim with `:q`.

Comment: I think the `argdo` version will work even as a `-c` (though you may need to watch out for the default value of 'hidden')

Comment: @Ben with `| update` at the end, `'hidden'` doesn't matter though... right? You can do `vim -c 'argdo retab | %s/ /, / | update' -c 'q' file*.txt`, that should work.

Comment: *should* work :) I seem to have hazy memories of something going wrong like that, though I could have been forgetting `| update`

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, open all the files in vim, and then execute `:Bufdo retab`

```
function! Bufdo(command)
  let curbuf=bufnr("%")
  execute 'bufdo ' . a:command
  execute 'buffer ' . curbuf
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Bufdo call Bufdo(<q-args>)
```

Answer (score 1):

A trivial way without complex commands is to use recording and replays (`help q` and `help @`).

Specifically you'll

1. open all the files at once

```bash
$ vim file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
# (Now you should be seeing contents of `file1.txt`)
```

2. Press `qq` (actually any letter may come after `q` since it refers to a register, but `qq` is fastest to type), you'll see `recording @q` in the status line. Any subsequent operations will be recorded to `@q`.
3. Perform your changes to `file1.txt` e.g. `:retab`and `:%s/ /,/` . The recording mechanism will save these operations to the register `q` so you may replay it in the future.
4. Save the changes to `file1.txt`, and goto the next file with `:wne`
5. Finish recording by pressing `q`. Now in `q` contains commands to execute your modifications and go to the next file.
6. Replay those commands by pressing `@q`. You should see the modifications being made to `file2.txt` and finally going to `file3.txt`
7. Repeat `@q` until you see `E165: Cannot go beyond last file`, that's when the job's done.